# Cognos Duplicate maximum count Column value

Tags: report, cognos-10

I am trying to flag the occurrences of a data item in column `[Customer]` determined by column `[Division]` and set three values for it in column `[flag]`.
 If  data item `[Customer]` has both ‘Q’ and ‘Z’ data item values for column `[Division]` in separate rows I want the value of the data item `[flag]` set to 2 for every repeated occurrence of data item `[Customer]` where customer is a member of both ‘Q’ AND ‘Z’ Division.
 If this condition exists I want the value of the `[flag]` column equal to 2 for all rows where the `[Customer]` column value occurs.
 If data item value `[Division]` for `[Customer]` is only ‘Q’ then set `[flag]` to 1 and if data item value `[Division]` for `[Customer]` is only ‘Z’ then set `[flag]` to 0.
 There are thousands of possible values for the `[Customer]` column data item and multiple rows can contain the desired `[customer] / [flag]` combinations.
 **How would I create column `[flag]` in the example below?**
 I want Customer separated by unique values.
 Notice Customer X is repeated 3 times and Customer A is repeated twice and the value in the `[flag]` column for each is 2 - `ALL [flag]` values where a customer is repeated In a row is 2.

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
   Customer    Rep    division  Count
       A   :    1   :    Q   :    1
       B   :    2   :    Z   :    0
       X   :    3   :    Q   :    2
       X   :    4   :    Z   :    2
       X   :    4   :    Q  :     2
       D   :    5   :    Z   :    0
       S   :    3   :    Q   :    2
       H   :    4   :    Q   :    1
       S   :    4   :    Z   :    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this based on your expanded explanation:

```
CASE count(distinct [division] for [Customer]) 
WHEN 2 THEN 2 
WHEN 1 AND [division] = 'Q' THEN 1 
WHEN 1 AND [division] = 'Z' THEN 0 
END
```

We count the distinct values of 'division' for every value of 'Customer'. If the count is 2 we know that both 'Q' and 'Z' are represented and we output the integer 2. If the count is 1 and the value of 'division' is 'Q' then we output 1. Lastly, if the count is 1 and 'division' is 'Z' then we output 0.

Assuming 'Q' and 'Z' are the only possible values for 'division' you can safely change the last test to: ELSE 0 to simplify. I included the full logic for clarity.

Comment: count([Customer] for report)

This only gives the TOTAL count of ALL data items. I want Customer separated by unique values. Notice Customer X is duplicated 3 times and the value in the count column for each - ALL count values of customer X rows is 2. Can you revaluate you answer?

Comment: I should rephrase the question there is more to it than just this.

Comment: I am trying to seperate repeated occurences from distinct occurences of a customer based on division.
If the customer is in both Q and Z I want to set a flag to 2.
If the customer is only in Q (can be multiple times) set the flag to 1 and if the customer is in Z (can be multiple times) set it to 0.
I want these values for conditional styling

Comment: OK. I rewrote the answer to reflect this new requirement.